# Getting SmoothDivScroll to start at the center of the scrollable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, positioning

I'm trying to get jQuery plugin SmoothDivScroll (http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) to start at the center of its contained content so there are scrollbars to the left and right on load. I'm aware that there's a startAtElementId option, but this doesn't allow me to start at the center.

I've tried calculating the centerpoint and applying it to the appropriate elements, but the left scroll always stops before it's expected to and the right elements float underneath.

Tried using this Js with no luck:

```
   $("div#scroller").smoothDivScroll();
   var halfWayDoc = $(document).width() / 2;
   var halfWayScrollArea = $("#scroller .scrollableArea").width() /2;
   var halfWay = halfWayDoc - halfWayScrollArea;
   var scrollArea = $("#scroller .scrollableArea").width(); 
   var scrollAreaAdjust = scrollArea + halfWay;
   $("#scroller .item:first-child").css("margin-left",halfWay);
   $("#scroller .item:last-child").css("margin-right",halfWay);
   $("#scroller .scrollableArea").width(scrollAreaAdjust);
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft"></div>
    <div class="scrollingHotSpotRight"></div>
    <div class="scrollWrapper">
        <div class="scrollableArea">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="assets/images/detail/Erdem-A-W-11-B2-sml.jpg" alt="example"/> 
            </div>  
                        ...
            <div class="item">
                <img src="assets/images/detail/Erdem-A-W-11-B2-sml.jpg" alt="example"/> 
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Cheers, 
Shaun

Comment: Would you please use JsFiddle to simulate the issue? It's much easier for us to help you with that :-)

Comment: @Qorbani I've added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunmorrison/4JeSv/26/ – note how first item has negative margin (off page) but second item won't go beyond window boundaries. 

Also items are incorrectly shunted below because of 'scrollableArea' width despite having margins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that I suggest :-)

```
// Element for Scroll
var scrollElement = $("div#scroller");

// Enable Smooth Div Scroll
scrollElement.smoothDivScroll();

// Find out Scrollable area's width
var halfWidth = $("div#scroller .scrollableArea").width()/2;

// Force scroller to move to half width :-)
scrollElement.data("scrollWrapper").scrollLeft(halfWidth);
```

I update the fiddle, so you can take a look at this update one:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3A9Zy/

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: this seems to work great! The only issue I see is if the wrapping DIV is set to 100%, then the left/first image seems always sit flush with the left-hand side of the window no-matter what width you have have the viewport at. e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunmorrison/3A9Zy/2/ – thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The basic sample in the site http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#quickdemo is having the functionality implemented. The animation starts from an image with ID "startAtMe"

`$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ autoScroll: "onstart", 
                                                        autoScrollDirection: "backandforth",
                                                        autoScrollStep: 1,
                                                        autoScrollInterval: 15,
                                                        startAtElementId: "startAtMe",
                                                        visibleHotSpots: "always" });`

. Did you try by specifying an id to the element you want to start with and passing the startAtElementId: "startAtMe" to the smoothDivScroll function?

Comment: Yes, that relies on specifiying an item to start on. I need to calculate the exact halfway point of the scrollable area to display in the centre of the screen on load.Thanks for your suggestion though.